# No matching provisioning profile found error

Tags: ios

Im getting the following error while trying to upload my app to appstore

```
No matching provisioning profiles found.
None of the valid provisioning profiles allowed the special entitlement. beta-reports-active , aps environment
```

How can I be able to sort this out?

1. I have tried to regerate the profile
2. I tried changing the OS Build number from plist file
3. I tried restarting xcode

but nothing works

Comment: The very first step would be to Google the error message. Is there nothing helpful in the results?

Comment: I have posted what I have tried after referring google